# What does the os.Stdin store and what does it mean?

Tags: go, pointers, operating-system, stdin

When I run fmt.Println(*os.Stdin) in golang, the output is this memory address {0xc000182000}
What does this address signify and how does the reading works?

Comment: This doesn’t mean anything. Reading from os.Stdin work by calling the read method. You don’t learn from fmt.Prinln stuff.

Comment: The program displays the fields of an `os.File`.  See the [source code](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/master:src/os/) for information on how an `os.File` is implemented.   It’s rare for a Go programer to peek into these details.

Answer (score -1):

The best way to find what is happening is to just look at the code in the standard library. The easiest way to do that is just google it:

https://www.google.com/search?q=os.Stdin

There is a URL in the first few links

[pkg.go.dev/os](http://pkg.go.dev/os)

There you can find a definition for Stdin:

```
Stdin  = NewFile(uintptr(syscall.Stdin), "/dev/stdin")
```

So what function NewFile generate?

https://pkg.go.dev/os#NewFile

> NewFile returns a new File with the given file descriptor and name. The returned value will be nil if fd is not a valid file descriptor. On Unix systems, if the file descriptor is in non-blocking mode, NewFile will attempt to return a pollable File (one for which the SetDeadline methods work).
> After passing it to NewFile, fd may become invalid under the same conditions described in the comments of the Fd method, and the same constraints apply.

This means NewFile will return pointer to structure that representing a File.

```
// File represents an open file descriptor.
type File struct {
    *file // os specific
}
```

Ok so that means os.Stdin representing a file. But what we can do with pointer on that File struct? If we use that as a parameter for fmt.Println we get address where that pointer is stored in memory. But that struct has Read method. We can find all methods implemented for that File struct in os/file.go file.

https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.17.5:src/os/file.go;l=112;drc=a25c58462992704dbb6819769f530b6cc6a8ebe3

there is a Read method that reads bytes from the underlying file to the byte array provided as a method parameter.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    byteSlice := []byte{}

    b1 := make([]byte, 1)
    for {
        _, err := os.Stdin.Read(b1)
        if err == io.EOF {
            break
        }
        if err != nil {
            log.Printf("Unknown error: %+v ", err.Error())
            os.Exit(1)
        }
        byteSlice = append(byteSlice, b1...)
    }

    fmt.Printf("we read: %s \n", string(byteSlice))
}
```

This code is extremely inefficient and should be used only for demonstration purposes. But I hope you get an idea of how you can read from os.Stdin and what stdin representing.